# JSR 303 / ConstraintValidatorContext: Parameterized Error Messages

Tags: java, validation, bean-validation

if I have a `ConstraintValidatorContext` and I'm constructing a `ConstraintViolationContextBuilder` using `buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate(String messageTemplate)`, is there any possibility to pass custom parameter values?

The corresponding properties file would look somehow like this:

```
Foobar.invalidValue.message=Invalid value. Valid values are {VALID_VALUES}
```

I then would like to programmatically set the value for `{VALID_VALUES}`.

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only refer to attributes of the concerned constraint annotation within message templates, e.g. like so for a constraint with attributes `min` and `max`:

```
size must be between {min} and {max}
```

So you could specify your valid values as annotation attribute.

If you're using Hibernate Validator as Bean Validation provider, you might implement a custom [ResourceBundleLocator](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html/validator-bootstrapping.html#section-resource-bundle-locator) which returns bundles with keys for your values:

```
public class MyResourceBundleLocator implements ResourceBundleLocator {

    public ResourceBundle getResourceBundle(Locale locale) {
        //return a bundle with keys for your values, e.g. set dynamically
    }
}
```

Then set the locator when obtaining a validator:

```
Validator validator Validation.byProvider(HibernateValidator.class)
    .configure()
    .messageInterpolator(
        new ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator(
            new MyResourceBundleLocator() ) )
    .buildValidatorFactory()
    .getValidator();
```

Alternatively you could just format and prepare the message yourself and pass it to `buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate()`.

Comment: Thank you very much for this extensive explanation :) !

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that allows customized Constraint annotations with parameterized error messages: see this question for more details: [Parameterized error messages for javax.validation.constraints.Pattern annotation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25651605/parameterized-error-messages-for-javax-validation-constraints-pattern-annotation/25673431#25673431)